# How to use `this` like an object and get its variables/functions by a string?

Tags: javascript, object, this

I've got an object.

```
function Obj()
{

}

Obj.prototype.doSomething = function(thing)
{
    this["do" + thing]();
}

Obj.prototype.doAlert = function()
{
    alert("Alert!");
}

var obj = new Obj();
obj.doSomething("Alert");
```

This is just a shortened down version of my object, and is a lot bigger.

What I would like to do is that if you pass in `'Alert'` it will run `this.doAlert();` and if I pass in `'Homework'` it will run `this.doHomework()`;

Obviously, in this case, it is stupid to do it like this, but my final project is going to be completely different.

It works fine with `window` like this:

```
window["do" + thing]();
```

but I don't want it to be a global function, but to be part of `obj`.

Does anyone have an idea how I'd go about doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `this["do" + thing]();`

Comment: @vlaz That's what they're already doing?

Comment: @vlaz this is what I've got so far but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Working here: https://jsfiddle.net/kbze3zh8/

Comment: OK, I missed that part. In that case, why does it not work?

Comment: Let me look into it and I'll see what I could have done wrong.

Comment: that work perfectly on my computer. Give us the bug report you obtain

Comment: Although the way you are calling the methods of your object is peculiar, it works fine. What seems to be your problem?

Comment: It is unclear what this question is actually about any more.  The method of calling you have in your question already works. Not sure what problem is still here?

Comment: @jfriend00 It seems what is happening is that the `this` inside the `doAlert` function is `window`. So when I do `this.console.log("Alert!")`, it does `window.console.log` instead. (**I have a custom textarea console in the html**, and it is using the default console instead.)

Comment: I got it to work! I will post an answer now.

Comment: Well, the text of your question does not describe that problem at all.  That's what I'm saying.  Instead, it describes a problem that is actually not a problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out that when you get the function through `this['functionName']`, `this` is not bound to it.

This means you cannot use `this.foo` inside any function called like above.

To fix this, I used the following code:

```
this["do" + thing].bind(this)();
```

instead of `this["do" + thing]();`

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/auk1f8ua/

Comment: When you use `this['functionName']()`, `this` will be passed as the `this` value of the method. Using `bind` is pointless.

Comment: I don't know why I had to do it but for some reason when I didn't bind it, and I `console.log`ged `this`, it showed everything in `window`, instead of `this`. It worked for me anyway.